# Does ROR 4 auto generate rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm re-running the Hartl ROR3 tutorial on ROR4

I'm noticing that even after adding rspec...

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

...that I'm not seeing rspec invoke when I create controllers...

```
>rails generate controller Pages home contact
  create  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
   route  get "pages/contact"
   route  get "pages/home"
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/pages
  create    app/views/pages/home.html.erb
  create    app/views/pages/contact.html.erb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/pages_helper.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/pages.css.scss
```

How does ROR4 handle auto generating rspec, or does it?

Answer (score 0):

Auto generation of controller specs defaults to true on ROR 4 as it does on ROR 3, per the following section from the help documentation generated by `rails g controller`:

```
Rspec options:
  [--controller-specs]  # Indicates when to generate controller specs
                        # Default: true
  [--view-specs]        # Indicates when to generate view specs
                        # Default: true
```

Could it be that you've configured Rails to use something other than the default?

Comment: Well certainly not intentionally. So 4 is supposed to generate rspec same as 3?

Comment: That's how I read it and that's how it's behaving for me. I even tried removing the `spec` directory to see if it's absence kept the specs from being created, but it did not.

Comment: Can you post your gemfile?